# Fedora Linux: transient failure downloading security updates

Tags: fedora, gnome, dnf

This is part N of "why aren't I getting security updates".  What causes this one?

- OS: Fedora Workstation 23
- Date: 2016-03-03

### 1. transient meaning failure, then success

`# dnf check-update`

`Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates' from 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/23/x86_64/': Yum repo downloading error: Downloading error(s): repodata/0e95ae636347564e66b0e600c9a1369d5c57415ed969bc7bba13e1a190d195c1-filelists.xml.gz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success; repodata/33467a86da0d3b3b24c27bf054700c0e35041a0643054e62f961d687b2a8c628-prestodelta.xml.xz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success; repodata/6ae21040c8354039ebdaebd0b3ebb99d6b577c0231e83faf5fdd906944bf32ee-primary.xml.gz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success; repodata/125571cd75bc296f2b59a8f11d92652f8faa8cbfc9e0fe0637b37c26e9a258fd-updateinfo.xml.xz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success`

#### 1.1 so there was an failure, what does wget show?

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/23/x86_64/repodata/0e95ae636347564e66b0e600c9a1369d5c57415ed969bc7bba13e1a190d195c1-filelists.xml.gz
--2016-03-03 23:32:47--  http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/23/x86_64/repodata/0e95ae636347564e66b0e600c9a1369d5c57415ed969bc7bba13e1a190d195c1-filelists.xml.gz
Resolving download.fedoraproject.org (download.fedoraproject.org)... 140.211.169.206, 85.236.55.6, 152.19.134.198, ...
Connecting to download.fedoraproject.org (download.fedoraproject.org)|140.211.169.206|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/23/x86_64/repodata/0e95ae636347564e66b0e600c9a1369d5c57415ed969bc7bba13e1a190d195c1-filelists.xml.gz [following]
--2016-03-03 23:32:48--  https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/23/x86_64/repodata/0e95ae636347564e66b0e600c9a1369d5c57415ed969bc7bba13e1a190d195c1-filelists.xml.gz
Resolving www.mirrorservice.org (www.mirrorservice.org)... 212.219.56.184
Connecting to www.mirrorservice.org (www.mirrorservice.org)|212.219.56.184|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-03-03 23:32:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

#### 1.2 just to be clear, there is no HTTP proxy to worry about here

```
# echo $http_proxy

#
```

#### 1.3 scratch my head, try again

`# dnf check-update`

`Fedora 23 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                1.3 MB/s |  20 MB     00:15`

`google-chrome                                                                                                55 kB/s | 3.4 kB     00:00`

`Last metadata expiration check performed 0:00:00 ago on Thu Mar  3 23:35:26 2016.`

`google-chrome-stable.x86_64                                           49.0.2623.75-1                                           google-chrome`

^ obviously [this includes security updates](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/stable-channel-update.html)...

`graphite2.x86_64                                                      1.3.6-1.fc23                                             updates`

....[Fedora security update](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/package-announce/2016-March/178192.html)...

`pcre.x86_64                                                           8.38-6.fc23                                              updates`

...[another Fedora security update](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/package-announce/2016-March/178193.html).

### 1.4 NOTE

I then looked at the directory on mirrorservice.org in my browser (i.e. after the successful update check).  The filelist had changed name to 85f1054756ada3a2a9ab2f6c40c23378c74afb22ba4599c3cbb46334be0820a1-filelists.xml.gz.  So we were trying to fetch an old file which had been deleted.

## 2. Context

The investigation above started because I noticed the Fedora security updates above, but GNOME wasn't notifying me about them.  GNOME Software showed 0 updates even after clicking refresh, which is not the behaviour I would expect.

`pkcon update` *did* show updates, although I forgot to record it.  I don't know whether it included the security updates at that point.

After the successful update check with `dnf`, refreshing GNOME Software showed updates.  At the time of writing, I know that dnf and PackageKit-on-Fedora use totally distinct cache directories.  Therefore `dnf` populating it's cache was *not* the direct cause for GNOME Software to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess was that mirrorservice.org didn't read the [instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring#Mirroring) and don't know how to mirror. In other words, their repository could appear inconsistent while it's being updated.  The old `filelists.xml.gz` could be deleted before `repomd.xml` is updated to point to the new filelist.  But it's very strange that such a big mirror would get it wrong.

Then I remembered the problem.  **`download.fedoraproject.org` is just [broken](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1003637#c16).**  It redirects you to different repositories for each request.  The problem is  you can't assume individual repositories will update at exactly the same time.  (And Fedora's master repository isn't formatted to support this, because it doesn't keep the previous filelist around).

**The default configuration doesn't use download.fedoraproject.org, so it's fine**.  This only happened because I switched from `metalink` downloads and un-commented the default `baseurl` line, in the `.repo` config files.  `baseurl` is great if you create your own Fedora repository to use locally, but otherwise you want to use the default `metalink` system, where your computer chooses which repositories(s) to download from.

In my case the inconsistency was probably between mirrorservice.org and the bytemark mirror.  You can see the redirects with curl:

```
$ curl --head http://download.fedoraproject.org/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2016 15:34:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5
Location: https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux//
AppTime: D=328174
AppServer: proxy02.fedoraproject.org
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

$ curl --head http://download.fedoraproject.org/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2016 15:35:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5
Location: http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/fedora/linux//
AppTime: D=363432
AppServer: proxy07.fedoraproject.org
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```